# How is new data loaded into Qlikview?

Tags: ram, qlikview

Sorry for the high-level question but so much of the basic information on Qlikview is sales material its hard to get a clear answer.

My understanding is that Qlikview stores unaggregated data in memory i.e. in RAM.

Obviously data will then change in the source so what is the basic method that Qlikview uses to incorporate that new data e.g. is there a load and process step that has to be scheduled for example?

In my mind for the data to go from being in a table to being in RAM it would be like processing a cube where is an explicit task that specifically filters in new data to be added in to a dedicated repository.

Any help or links to this topic would be most appreciated

Comment: You can get all the info you need for Qlikview from the Qlikview Community : http://community.qlikview.com/welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QlikView you have an *Load-Script* where you decide **what** you load (SQL, xls, csv, html, qvd) and **how** you want to do it.

In scenarios where actuality is not relevant you can start your loadscript manually when ever you need it.

If you need near-time data you can automate the load process on the server and the publisher delivers the new preloaded data when it is available.

In both cases you can also work with incremental loads.

Comment: Thanks! I think the term 'Load Script' was the nugget of information I needed.. thanks again